# How to handle enable/disable notifications from setting in iOS from react-native/expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm currently working on a mobile app with expo. I'm using the [expo-notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) package. The example show how to request permission for notifications and how to get the expo push token once approved.

I'm wondering how this flow works for the following scenario:

- A user does not enable notification first time gets asked in the app, but later from the settings and it does not go back and open the app so I can check permission. How do I get the expo push token, so I can send store it in my db?

I have not tried anything because I'm not sure how to implement that scenario.

I'm expecting that I should be notified when the user enables or disables notifications from settings menu (iOS or Android) so I can take action.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Permissions module to verify whether the user has allowed or denied permission for your app to dispatch notifications. Here's an example code to do so:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Notifications } from 'expo';

async function checkNotificationPermission() {
  const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
  if (status === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted');
  } else {
    console.log('Notification permission not granted');
  }

  const isEnabled = await Notifications.isEnablesAsync();
  if (isEnabled) {
    console.log('Notifications enabled');
  } else {
    console.log('Notifications disabled');
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you :D

Comment: Hi Louay thanks for suggestions. I think this works if the user enables notifications from settings AND goes back and open the app. That way I check permission. I'm talking about the user enables permission from setting BUT does not open the app, so how can I know notifications are enable if the user does not open the app. makes sense?

Comment: It is not possible to check if the user has disabled notifications for a specific app without opening the app.